# $(a, b) = (b, c) = (a, c) = 1$ implies $(c^2, ab) = (ab, a^n - b^n) = (c^2, a^n - b^n) = 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let
$n \geq 3$
be an integer.
If $a, b, c > 0$
are integers such that
$(a, b) = (b, c) = (a, c) = 1$,
is it necessary that
$$(c^2, ab) = (ab, a^n - b^n) = (c^2, a^n - b^n) = 1$$

Comment: It is true that $(a,bc)=1$ follows from $(a,b),(a,c)=1$. It is also true that $(a,a^n-b^n)=(a,-b^n)=(a,b^n)=(a,b)=1$ since $a^n-b^n=-b^n\mod a$, the same with $(bc,a^n-b^n)$. In general, if $b=b'\mod a$, $(a,b)=(a,b')$.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I have typed wrong equations. So sorry. Note that Pedro Tamaroff left the comment in order to answer the first version of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equality $(c^2,ab)=1$ follows from the fact that $a$, $b$, and $c$ share no prime factors, since then $c^2$ and $ab$ share no prime factors as well.

For the equality $(ab, a^n-b^n) = 1$, consider a prime factor of $ab$. It either divides $a$ or $b$ but not both since $(a,b) = 1$, so it does not divide $a^n-b^n$.

For the final equality $(c^2, a^n-b^n) = 1$, consider some prime $p$ dividing $c$. Assume that it divides $a^n-b^n$. Therefore, $a^n \equiv b^n$ modulo $p$. From here it is easy to construct a counterexample. For example, we can take $c = 7$, $a = 4$, $b = 11$, and $n = 3$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If $d$ divides $ab,a^n-b^n$, $d$ will divide $$a^{n-1}(ab)-b(a^n-b^n)=b^{n+1}$$

Similarly, $d$ will divide $$b^{n-1}(ab)+a(a^n-b^n)=a^{n+1}$$

$\implies d$  will divide $(a^{n+1},b^{n+1})$

Now, if prime $p$ divides $a^{n+1},p$ must divide $a$

So if prime $q$ divides $a^{n+1},b^{n+1}, q$ must divide $(a,b)$

More generally,  $(a^m,b^m)=(a,b)^m$ for integer $m\ge0$

Comment: Wish I know the mistake here

Answer (score 0):

$\forall x, y, z, n \in \mathbb{Z}$:

1. $(x,y) = (x, z) = 1$ implies $(x,yz) = 1$.
2. $(x,y) = 1$ implies $(x^2, y) = 1$
3. $(x,y) = 1$ implies $(x, x^n + y^n) = 1$
4. $(x,y) = 1$ implies $(x, x^n - y^n) = 1$

You can use these 4 lemmas to prove all those gcd's are 1.

Proof of 1:

Given $(x,y) = 1$ and $(x,z) = 1$, from Bézout's identity, $\exists a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that $ax + by = 1$ and $cx + dz = 1$.

$$\begin{align}
(ax + by)(cx + dz) & = 1\\
acx^2 + adxz + bcxy + bdyz &= 1\\
(acx + adz + bcy)x + bdyz & = 1 \\
(x,yz) & = 1
\end{align}$$

Proof of 2:

Given $(x,y) = 1$, again from Bézout's identity $ax + by = 1$.

$$\begin{align}
(ax + by)^2 & = 1\\
a^2x^2 + 2abxy + b^2y^2 & = 1\\
x(a^2x + 2aby) + y^2(b^2) & = 1\\
(x,y^2) &= 1\\
\end{align}$$

Proof of 3:
Assuming $n \ge 2$, since $n=1$ is trivial.
$$\begin{align}
ax + by & = 1\\
(ax + by)^n & = 1\\
\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}(ax)^i(by)^{n-i} & = 1\\
a^nx^n + b^ny^n + \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{i}(ax)^i(by)^{n-i}  & = 1\\
\text{Note that the sum is divisible by x}\\
b^n(x^n + y^n) + (a^n - b^n)x^n + x\sum & = 1\\
(x^n + y^n, x) & = 1\\
\end{align}$$

Proof of 4:

$n=1$ is trivial.  $ax + by = 1$ implies $(a + b)x + (-b)(x - y) = 1$.

For even $n = 2j$, $x^n - y^n = x^{2j} - y^{2j} = (x^j + y^j)(x^j - y^j)$.  Now we can just use 
lemma 1 along with inductive uses of 3 and 4.

For odd $n = 2j+1$,

$$\begin{align}
ax - by & = 1\\
(ax - by)^{2j+1} & = 1\\
\sum_{i=0}^{2j+1} \binom{2j+1}{i}(ax)^i(-by)^{2j+1-i} & = 1\\
a^{2j+1}x^{2j+1} - b^{2j+1}y^{2j+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{2j} \binom{2j+1}{i}(ax)^i(-by)^{2j+1-i} & = 1\\
\text{again, the sum is divisible by x}\\
b^{2j+1}(x^{2j+1} - y^{2j+1}) + x(a^{2j+1} - b^{2j+1}) + x\sum & = 1\\
(x^{2j+1} - y^{2j+1}, x) & = 1\\
\end{align}$$